# How to get what changes were made in what files as part of git commit?

Tags: git, version-control, commit

Is there a way to get information about what changes were made in which files as part of a commit?

I know that there is a way to get details about all commits: `git log -p`

My specific use-case involves getting more details about a bunch of commit ids. I already have the commit ids, i know i can get a list of files that were changed as part of these commits. But how do i get the actual changes  that were made in only these commits?

Thanks.

Comment: i guess one way would be to do a `git log -p <file-name>` , once i have the files which were changed as part of commit x. But is there a more direct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you don't like about `git log -p <commit>` is the fact that it walks the tree and shows parent commits, you can just limit it to the single commit by saying `git log -1 -p <commit>`. `git show <commit>` should also work. If you want to show the changes made without the commit header that shows dates/authors/etc., you can do `git log -p -1 --pretty=format: <commit>` (this will essentially just show the `git diff` output, which of course you could also get by doing `git diff <commit>~1 <commit>`).

There are probably other options if you can better clarify exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

are you looking for `git show $ID`

Answer (score 1):

If the revision where changes started was `refa` (non inclusive) and the ending ref is `refn` then you could:

```
git diff refa..refn
```